# How to count five every time instead of one

Tags: javascript, html, css, onclick, operators

You see when I first click the button it adds 6 not five, and after that it just adds 1 every time. I don't know how to fix this because I don't know anything about javascript. And when it gets to 100¢ is it possible to make it $1 and then if you click it again it goes to $1.01 and then $1.02 and so on.

```js
var number = 5

function plusOne(value) {
  number++;
  count.textContent = number.toString();
}
```

```css
#coin {
  background-image: url("http://pngimg.com/uploads/coin/coin_PNG36868.png");
  border: none;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 200px 200px;
  background-color: white;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
#coin:active {
  width: 190px;
  height: 190px;
  background-size: 190px 190px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Coin Clicker</title>
</head>
</html>

<html>
<body>

<div>
  <span id="count">0</span><span>¢</span>
</div>

<div>
  <button id="coin" onclick="plusOne(value)" alt="coin"></button>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to count five every time instead of one

`number++` basically means `number + 1`. Just change the initial value of `number` to `0` and change `number++` to `number = number + 5` like this:

```
function plusOne(value) {
  number += 5; // this is equivalent to "number = number + 5"
  count.innerHTML = number.toString();
}
```

> And when it gets to 100¢ is it possible to make it $1 and then if you
> click it again it goes to $1.01 and then $1.02 and so on.

Just add a second variable called say, `dollar` and use an if/else condition to add the dollar value along with the `0.01` addition instead once you reached `100¢` like this:

```
let number = 0;
let dollar = 1;

function plusOne() {
  if(number < 95) {
    number += 5; // this is equivalent to "number = number + 5"
    count.innerHTML = number.toString() + '</span><span>¢</span>';
  } else {
    dollar += 0.01;
    count.innerHTML = dollar.toFixed(2).toString() + '</span><span>$</span>';
  }
}
```

Check and run the following code snippet for a practical example of the above code:

```js
let number = 0;
let dollar = 1;

function plusOne() {
  if(number < 95) {
    number += 5; // this is equivalent to "number = number + 5"
    count.innerHTML = number.toString() + '</span><span>¢</span>';
  } else if(number < 100) {
    number += 5; // add 5 to number but start inserting the "dollar" value to html now
    count.innerHTML = dollar.toString() + '</span><span>$</span>';
  } else {
      dollar += 0.01;
      count.innerHTML = dollar.toFixed(2).toString() + '</span><span>$</span>';
  }
}

document.querySelector('#coin').addEventListener('click', plusOne);
```

```css
#coin {
  background-image: url("http://pngimg.com/uploads/coin/coin_PNG36868.png");
  border: none;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 200px 200px;
  background-color: white;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
#coin:active {
  width: 190px;
  height: 190px;
  background-size: 190px 190px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span id="count">0</span>
</div>

<div>
  <button id="coin" alt="coin"></button>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks! this one is the most helpful. one problem I just realized. when I make this my own .html file it doesn't work anymore. or when I use this out of stackoverflow. why?

Comment: @Arcadesmasher1.0 Make sure your JavaScript is added after your HTML otherwise querySelector won't be able to find the HTML element.

Comment: @Arcadesmasher1.0 The new updated code should switch from 95¢ to 1$. The above code is working as it should in JSFiddle as well: https://jsfiddle.net/AndrewL64/2t8gLsoy/

Comment: oh yea it does. it wasnt updating for me

Answer (score 2):

start the variable at "0" because when you click on the button, the script already adds +5 to the variable. Easier to change the value of the variable by using `number = number + 5;`

If you want an anser to your second question open a second question with it and show the attempt to solve the 2nd Question.

```js
var number = 0;

function plusOne(value) {
  number = number + 5;
  count.textContent = number.toString();
}
```

```css
#coin {
  background-image: url("http://pngimg.com/uploads/coin/coin_PNG36868.png");
  border: none;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 200px 200px;
  background-color: white;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
#coin:active {
  width: 190px;
  height: 190px;
  background-size: 190px 190px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Coin Clicker</title>
</head>
</html>

<html>
<body>

<div>
  <span id="count">0</span><span>¢</span>
</div>

<div>
  <button id="coin" onclick="plusOne(value)" alt="coin"></button>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks, I actually kinda combined yours and the other answer so this one was helpful too!

Comment: @tacoshy is it not necessary to use `document.getElementById` for calling `id`

Comment: Does this apply for `class` also

Comment: @Rana? wrong post? where to I use an ID? my chanegs where only the variable value and `number++` to `number = number + 5`. I'm also quite aware of that. I'm not a rookie.

Comment: Yes , I know that but I am asking about `count` which is an `id` of `span` tag . As used in the question without `document.getElementById`

Comment: `count.textContent` used in the function , can we use a direct name call to `id` . Asking as curious question

Comment: `textContent` is part of `Node.js` its `element.textContent`. Element is either a variable or the id of an existing HTML element. as you can use in a variable you also could use directly `document.querySelector('.class')`

Answer (score 1):

Change `var number` to 1 if want to start from 1

And add this to function for increasing 5:

```
number = number + 5 ;
```

And add this to function for increasing 0.01:

```
numberChange = numberChange + 0.01 ;
```

to increase by 0.01 instead of `number++` as it will increase 1 on each click.

You may ask why used `number += 0.01` while above expression is different , well it is same as `number= number + 0.01` .
It works like this :

```
var number = 1;  
number = 1 + 0.01  
number = 1.01 
then number = number + 0.01  
number = 1.01 + 0.01
number  = 1.02  
then so on .....
```

`toFixed(2)` is to show results up to 2 decimal places only because when adding decimal numbers there will be difference in each iteration so to remove that.
[See this for `.toFixed`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tofixed.asp)

```js
var number = 90
var numberChange = 1

function plusOne(value) {
  number += 5;
  count.textContent = number.toString();
  changeCurSign.innerHTML = "¢";
  if (number > 99) {
    numberChange += 0.01;
    var reed = numberChange.toFixed(2)
    count.textContent = reed.toString();
    changeCurSign.innerHTML = "$";
  }
}
```

```css
#coin {
  background-image: url("http://pngimg.com/uploads/coin/coin_PNG36868.png");
  border: none;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 200px 200px;
  background-color: white;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

#coin:active {
  width: 190px;
  height: 190px;
  background-size: 190px 190px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Coin Clicker</title>
</head>

</html>

<html>

<body>

  <div>
    <span id="count">0</span><span id="changeCurSign">¢</span>
  </div>

  <div>
    <button id="coin" onclick="plusOne(value)" alt="coin"></button>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: thanks, even though the bottom one helps this one help more because it does the decimals.